# Shape mismatch between logits and labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, image-recognition

I am feeding my sensors with images which have shapes 160*60*1.

My CNN structure is like following

```
X_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 160 * 60])
X = tf.reshape(X_input, shape=[-1, 160, 60, 1])
Y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 5 * image_reader.NUM_CLASSES])

learning_rate = 0.001


def create_fully_connected_weight(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1))


def create_conv_weight(patch_height, patch_width, input_channel, output_channel):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape=[patch_height, patch_width, input_channel, output_channel], stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)


def create_bias(shape):
    initial = 0.1 * tf.random_normal(shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)


def create_strides(batch_step, height_step, width_step, channel_step):
    return [batch_step, height_step, width_step, channel_step]


def create_conv_layer(input, W, strides, padding='SAME'):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(input, W, strides, padding)


def apply_max_pool(x, ksize, strides, padding='SAME'):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize, strides, padding)


keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

W1 = create_conv_weight(5, 5, 1, 32)
print("W1 shape:", W1.get_shape())
B1 = create_bias([32])
strides1 = create_strides(1, 1, 1, 1)
Y1 = tf.nn.relu(create_conv_layer(X, W1, strides1, padding="SAME") + B1)
Y1 = apply_max_pool(Y1, [1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2, 1])
Y1 = tf.nn.dropout(Y1, keep_prob=keep_prob)
print(Y1)

W2 = create_conv_weight(5, 5, 32, 64)
print("W2 shape:", W2.get_shape())
B2 = create_bias([64])
strides2 = create_strides(1, 1, 1, 1)
Y2 = tf.nn.relu(create_conv_layer(Y1, W2, strides2, padding="SAME") + B2)
Y2 = apply_max_pool(Y2, [1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2, 1])
Y2 = tf.nn.dropout(Y2, keep_prob=keep_prob)
print(Y2)

W3 = create_conv_weight(5, 5, 64, 128)
print("W3 shape:", W3.get_shape())
B3 = create_bias([128])
strides3 = create_strides(1, 1, 1, 1)
Y3 = tf.nn.relu(create_conv_layer(Y2, W3, strides3, padding="SAME") + B3)
Y3 = apply_max_pool(Y3, [1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2, 1])
Y3 = tf.nn.dropout(Y3, keep_prob=keep_prob)
print(Y3)

# keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

Y3 = tf.reshape(Y3, [-1, 20 * 10 * 128])

W4 = create_fully_connected_weight([20 * 10 * 128, 1024])
print("W4 shape:", W4.get_shape())
B4 = create_bias([1024])
Y4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(Y3, W4) + B4)
Y4 = tf.nn.dropout(Y4, keep_prob=keep_prob)
print(Y4)

W5 = create_fully_connected_weight([1024, 5 * image_reader.NUM_CLASSES])
print("W5 shape:", W5.get_shape())
B5 = create_bias([5 * image_reader.NUM_CLASSES])
Ylogits = tf.matmul(Y4, W5) + B5
```

However, while I am trying to calculate the loss

```
cross_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=Ylogits, labels=Y_)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
```

I am taking an error which says Incompatible shapes: [200,55] vs. [250,55].
I think I have a problem that related with layers but I couldn't find it for hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if 'SAME' : output_shape[i] = ceil(input_spatial_shape[i] / strides[i])

```
Y1 - 160 ,60
Y1 - 80, 30 <= 160/2, 60/2
Y2 - 80, 30 
Y2 - 40, 15 <= 80/2, 30/2
Y3 - 40, 15
Y3 - 20, 8
```

I am confused how you are ending up with 20,10 before fully connected layers.

Also, the error you're getting looks like wrong batch_size (250 vs 200) ?

Would you please create a runnable script that has this error so that others can help.

Comment: you are quite right. My initial image height was 64 so I forgot to change it to 8 in the last layer. I am coding about 12 hours so forgive me :) thanks a lot for your help